# Can't register custom adjuster with Craft CMS commerce

Tags: craft3, plugin-development, plugin-craftcommerce, adjusters

following https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/adjusters.html#writing-an-adjuster I am trying to make a custom adjuster:

I placed

```
class myPlugin extends Plugin{
Event::on(
    OrderAdjustments::class,
    OrderAdjustments::EVENT_REGISTER_ORDER_ADJUSTERS,
    function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
        $event->types[] = Amss_StripeSurcharge::class;
    }
);
}
```

inside myPlugin.php

and in the same file I have

```
use craft\commerce\services\OrderAdjustments;
use yii\base\Event;
use Amss_StripeSurcharge;
```

included in the top.

I have the file Amss_StripeSurcharge.php in the same folder as myPlugin.php,

which currently just has code copied and pasted from the documentation.

However, when I press add items to cart, I get the error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to amss\amss\AMSS::amss\amss{closure}() must be an instance of amss\amss\RegisterComponentTypesEvent, instance of craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent given in C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\plugins\craft-AMSS\src\AMSS.php:205
> Stack trace:
> #0 [internal function]: amss\amss\AMSS->amss\amss{closure}(Object(craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent))
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Event.php(312): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent))
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php(637): yii\base\Event::trigger('craft\commerce\...', 'registerOrderAd...', Object(craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent))
> #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\commerce\src\services\OrderAdjustments.php(103): yii\base\Component->trigger('registerOrderAd...', Object(craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent))
> #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\commerce\src\elements\Order.php(1804): craft\commerce\services\OrderAdjustments->getAdjusters()
> #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\commerce\src\elements\Order.php(1905): craft\commerce\elements\Order->recalculate()
> #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\services\Elements.php(2666): craft\commerce\elements\Order->afterSave(false)
> #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\services\Elements.php(773): craft\services\Elements->_saveElementInternal(Object(craft\commerce\elements\Order), false, false, true)
> #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\commerce\src\controllers\CartController.php(403): craft\services\Elements->saveElement(Object(craft\commerce\elements\Order), false, false, true)
> #9 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\commerce\src\controllers\CartController.php(238): craft\commerce\controllers\CartController->_returnCart()
> #10 [internal function]: craft\commerce\controllers\CartController->actionUpdateCart()
> #11 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> #12 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(181): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
> #13 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Controller.php(190): yii\base\Controller->runAction('update-cart', Array)
> #14 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(534): craft\web\Controller->runAction('update-cart', Array)
> #15 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(276): yii\base\Module->runAction('commerce/cart/u...', Array)
> #16 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(585): craft\web\Application->runAction('commerce/cart/u...', Array)
> #17 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\web\Application.php(255): craft\web\Application->_processActionRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
> #18 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(392): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
> #19 C:\xampp\htdocs\newamss\craft\web\index.php(26): yii\base\Application->run()
> #20 {main}

myPlugin and myPlugin.php are just madeup names for what the name of the actual plugin is called, which is called amss

Any help on how I can fix this error would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error indicates that you're type-hinting the wrong class. Note this line in the error message:

> Argument 1 passed to amss\amss\AMSS::amss\amss{closure}() must be an instance of amss\amss\RegisterComponentTypesEvent, instance of craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent given

This comes from the type-hint in your function:

```php
    function(RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
        $event->types[] = Amss_StripeSurcharge::class;
    }
```

Since you're not specifying a full qualified namespace, the class name is evaluated relative to the current namespace. Looks like your file is namespaced as `amss\amss`, which means your type-hint essentially says *'This function expects an object of class `amss\amss\RegisterComponentTypesEvent`'*. But it receives an object of type `craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent`, so the runtime type-check throws an error.

To fix this, either specifiy a fully qualified namespace (`\craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent`) or import the class at the top of the file with a `use` statement:

```php
use craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent;
```

This tells PHP that in this file, the class name `RegisterComponentTypesEvent` refers to `craft\events\RegisterComponentTypesEvent`.

---

Once you've fixed this, you're might get another error because of this use-statement:

```php
use Amss_StripeSurcharge;
```

This would indicate that your `Amss_StripeSurcharge` class has no namespace (i.e. lives in the root namespace). Good practice would be to namespace that file and class (e.g. as `amss\amss\adjuster\Amss_StripeSurcharge`. So your `Amss_StripeSurcharge` class would look something like this:

```php
<?php
namespace amss\amss\adjuster;

class Amss_StripeSurcharge { /* ... */ }
```

Then you can add a `use` statement to import that class:

```php
use \amss\amss\adjustor\Amss_StripeSurcharge;
```

Make sure to read up on [how namespaces work in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to avoid errors like these!